# Stop autoescape of specific html tags in twig

Tags: html, twig

I am working with twig and want to stop autoescape of specific(not all) html tags like anchor tag. Is there a way to do this. My code is somewhat like this
    
      {{ content|nl2br}}
    
content contains anchor tags.
Since raw stops autoescape of all tags, I can't use it. 
Can anyone please suggest any solution for this.

Comment: You could write your own filter, which will need some effort from your side. Read this: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built in striptags filter like this:

`{{ "this <a>is my</a> <b>html<b> string"|striptags('<a>')|raw }}`

The `<a>` tag will remain but any other tag will be stripped out. The extra |raw filter will then make sure not to escape the `<a>` tag.

Note, this could still potentially cause issues with output if your string might contain other unsafe HTML characters like < or >. If your data is considered safe, then this will work, otherwise you'll probably have to build your own filter which really isn't all that hard.